# Comparing single characters with <charT>

Tags: c++, templates

I'm converting my JSON parser to support both `wchar_t` and `char`. Can I use `charT` (Character traits classes) for this? If so, then how can I compare single characters, currently this is how my code looks:

```
template <class charT>
class CQuickJson final
...
size_t CQuickJson::ParseStringArray(charT *jsonData, size_t pos)
{
    while (jsonData[pos] != L'\0')
    {
    switch (jsonData[pos])
    {
            case L' ':
            case L'\f':
            case L'\n':
            case L'\r':
            case L'\t':
            case L'\v':
            case L',':
                // Ignore whitespace characters and commas
                break;
            // ...
    }
}
```

As you see I try to check for certain wide character but I also want to check the same ASCII character, ie. `L'\f`' should also check for `'\f'` - I'm guessing a `static_cast<>` or something is needed here but I'm stuck as of yet.

Comment: I take it you are aware of http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/ ?

Comment: Can you describe `charT`? I.e. what do you mean with it?

Comment: @phresnel Character traits classes. http://www.cantrip.org/traits.html

Comment: I see. Note though that `charT` is not a general C++ term. If you mean certain traits, better be explicit.

Comment: @phresnel I've updated the question to clarify after your comment, thanks.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen: Seen that already; it just sounded as if you are still assuming `charT` to be part of C++ parlance. Just wanted to clarify on that, no evil intentions even if I sometimes sound like an arse ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure if this is what you are after, but you can create traits class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <class charT>
  struct js_traits { };

template <> struct js_traits<char> {
  static constexpr char txt_f() { return '\f'; }
  /// ..
};

template <> struct js_traits<wchar_t> {
  static constexpr wchar_t txt_f() { return L'\f'; }
  /// ..
};

template<class wcharT>
void test(const wcharT* s) {
    while(*s) {
     switch (*s) {
       case js_traits<wcharT>::txt_f():
       std::cout << "<f>";
       break;
       default:
       std::cout << *s;
     };       
     s++;
    } 
}

int main()
{
   test("test\f");
   std::cout << std::endl;
   test(L"test\f");
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

output:

```
test<f>    
116101115116<f>
```

tested with g++4.8
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b9e3b5f22eafcc0

or if `constexpr` is not allowed:

```
template <class charT>
  struct js_traits { };

template <> struct js_traits<char> {
  static const char txt_f = '\f';
  /// ..
};

template <> struct js_traits<wchar_t> {
  static const wchar_t txt_f = L'\f';
  /// ..
};
```

Comment: I'm getting `"a value of type "const __wchar_t (*)()" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "__wchar_t"` when assigning and `"expression must be an integral constant expression"` in the `switch` blocks. Any idea what could cause these compile-time errors?

Comment: The C++11 `constexpr` alternative I could not get to work with ICL, but the "old way" works ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably best thing to do would be to use `std::string`: this avoids all the mess with bare pointers *and* supports `char` as well as `wchar_t`.  And after all, you are dealing with json *strings*, not zero-terminated buffers with characters.

```
template<typename T>
size_t CQuickJson::parseString(const std::basic_string<T>& jsonData, size_t pos) 
{
   auto current = jsonData.begin();
   std::advance(current, pos);
   switch( *current ) {
     ...
   }
}
```

Comment: `string` supports `wchar_t`? really? why do we need `wstring` then?

Comment: @TemplateRex: You're right: that should ahve been `std::basic_string`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`std::ctype<charT>::narrow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype/narrow):

```
auto &loc = std::locale::classic();
assert(std::use_facet<std::ctype<wchar_t>>(loc).narrow(L' ', 0) == ' ');
assert(std::use_facet<std::ctype<char>>(loc).narrow(' ', 0) == ' ');
```

Note that you can use this in templated code even where `charT` is `char`, because `std::ctype<char>::narrow` is a no-op.